# is it possible to track offline sale conversion/ data on the Google AdWords and analytics?

Tags: google-ads-api

I have an offline sale and online site for that daily purchase and conversion are successfully tracked by the Google AdWords.
For offline sale, I want to track this conversion on the Adwords

Is it possible to send the sales data to the AdWords manually through the API or something?

If yes, can you please suggest the possible ways?

Answer (score 1):

If there is no activity on a given product online, Google AdWords will not be able to track this conversion.

On the other hand, if you have a product online and it doesn't lead to an online sale, but instead leads a customer down some path that eventually leads to an offline sale, then there is a way you can track this. You can prepare your data in a CSV format and import conversions from offline to AdWords. 
You need the

```
Google Click ID, Conversion Name, Conversion Time, Conversion Value, Conversion Currency
```

etc., to do the import.

For more information please refer to https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/7014069

Answer (score 0):

If you're keen to do some automation and your CRM or tracking system has the ability to fire webhooks, you can always connect with Zapier and push the conversion data to a google sheet connected to your adwords account. That will automate 95% of the workflow.

```
Google Click ID, Conversion Name, Conversion Time, Conversion Value, Conversion Currency
```